# Local optima of non-negative-least-squares?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

For a fixed matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the non-negative-least-square problem is given by

$$\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^m_{\geq 0}}{\arg \min} \ g(x), \ \ \ g(x) =  \vert \vert Ax-b\vert\vert^2.$$

Now, consider the Lagrangian
$$L(x,\mu) = g(x) + \mu^T x.$$

By the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, we have the following necessary conditions for $x^*$ to be a local optimum: There should exist $\mu \leq 0$ such that

- $ \nabla_x L(x^*,\mu) = 0$
- $ x^* \geq 0$
- $ {x^*}^T \mu = 0.$

The first condition reads
$$ A^T (Ax - b) +\mu = 0.$$
Together with the other conditions, this should yield the following property of entries $i$

$$(A^TAx^* - A^T b)_i=  0, \text{ if } {x^*}_i >0 $$

$$ (A^TAx^*  - A^T b)_i= \mu_i \text{ else }.$$

That is, in some sense the possible optimum $x^*$ solves the equation for some entries, and fails to do so for other entries.

Now, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares), this is a convex problem with a convex feasible set, so if I understand this correctly (I never really learned about optimization with inequality constraints) then there should be only one one global optimum of the solution.

There still could however exist other ${x^*}$

that fulfill the above conditions. I am wondering, since it might be a problem that can be reasonably well understood, whether one can understand these points ${x^*}$.

Why do they fail to be local-minima? Can we still interpret them in some meaningful way related to our objective? Or is my reasoning wrong all along?

Comment: How is a $\max$ a least squares problem?

Comment: @copper.hat fixed it

Comment: A local $\min$ is a global $\min$ if the cost and constraints are convex. It is straightforward to show. There may be many **minimisers** that attain that value.

Comment: @copper.hat that's true, but what if for example $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is invertible and $A^{-1}b \geq 0$, then this solution should be unique but there might still be other $x$ fulfilling the KKT conditions or is this not possible in that case?

Comment: If $A$ is injective then the cost is strictly convex. If there were two solutions then there would be a smaller one inbetween.

Comment: So you are saying in this case the KKT-conditions become sufficient conditions and thus a point $x^*$ fulfilling the conditions is automatically a minimizer and hence the only one?

Comment: Well, you don't need the KKT conditions to make that conclusion.

Comment: @copper.hat but in my assumptions $x^*$ is a point that fulfills the KKT-conditions, so how is this irrelevant?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you asking if the KKT conditions are sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking, with convex problems, necessary conditions are sufficient.

A nice characterisation of an optimal solution is: If the cost $f$ is convex & differentiable and the constraint set $C$ is convex, then $x^* \in C$ solves $\min_{x \in C} f(x)$ **iff** $df(x^*, x-x^*) \ge 0$ for all $x \in C$.

In terms of the above problem, if  $x^*$ satisfies the above conditions, we have, for **any** $x \ge 0$,
$\langle \nabla g(x^*), x-x^* \rangle = - \langle \mu^*, x-x^* \rangle = - \langle \mu^*, x \rangle \ge 0$,
and so $x^*$ is a solution.